# ADF Business Component prevent spaces in table column attribute

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a list of views based on entities in ADFBC Application.
I am displaying them in a table.

Supposed I have several tables such as SUPPLIERS, ITEMS etc that is based on the some entities..is there a way to prevent them from having spaces
in their column attributes?

```
Example:
SUPPLIERS
 - SUPPLIER_CODE
 - SUPPLIER_NAME

ITEMS
 - ITEM_CODE
 - ITEM_DESC
```

I want the SUPPLIER_CODE and the ITEM_CODE not to have any spaces...
so for these use case:

```
The following are valid
SUPPLIER_1, SUPPLIER_2, SUPPLIER_3
ITEM_1, ITEM_2, ITEM_3

but the following should not be allowed
SUPPLIER 1, SUPPLIER 2, SUPPLIER 3
ITEM 1, ITEM 2, ITEM 3
```

Should user leave this attribute in an input text, the following message should be displayed in the User Interfaces.. "Spaces are not allowed in this column attribute"

Is there a way to make these changes in one place so that view attribute that requires this will be affected and skipped for those that does not require this check?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are having a view object SuppliersVO.xml, you can expose the row implementation: SuppliersVORowImpl.java

Then, inside the methods: setSupplierCode(String val) and setSupplierName(String val), do something like:

```
public void setSupplierCode(String val) {
 if(val != null)
   val = <do your trimming here>

  this.setAttributeInternal(SUPPLIERCODE, val);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Florin..but this means that I will do this in each VORowImpl..then what if I have multiple VORowImpl for different tables then is there a way to do this in one place?  Also, how can I raised an exception such that when user enters a code with spaces then, the JSF/JSPX page should display that error.  I am not that of an expert on ADFBC so please be patient with me.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention..I don't want users to enter a code with spaces..so I don't want to do any trimming here.

Comment: @MarkEstrada you can't do it in only one place. one option is to throw JboException in the method from rowImpl for each VO with a text message for users, or in the page add a regex validation on top of the inputtext which throws error if space is detected.